# How to construct an Association

Tags: functions, function-construction, associations

I have two lists of the following form:

```
a = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}
b = {{1 , 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
```

How do I construct an Association like this?

```
A = <|{a, b, c} -> {1, 2, 3}, {d, e, f} ->  {4, 5, 6}, {g, h, i} -> {7, 8, 9}|>
```

Comment: Use, say, `aa` and `bb` on the left-hand-side of your assignments, then use `AssociationThread[aa,bb]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to either assume that elements of the list ***a*** are strings, or rename the list variable to something else, otherwise you get a recursive call, because ***a*** is the first element of that list. Assuming you do one of these:

```
a = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}}
b = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
```

Then the association is constructed with:

```
<|Thread[a -> b]|>
```

> <|{"a", "b", "c"} -> {1, 2, 3}, {"d", "e", "f"} -> {4, 5, 6}, {"g", 
>      "h", "i"} -> {7, 8, 9}|>